# Why does the react-native-permissions cannot request the permission in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-permissions

**Information**

I tried to create an app to request permission in the react native side. There is a button in a screen to be clicked to check and request permission.

**Problem**

react-native-permission link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions

When I follow the instruction in the link and create a demo app, **I cannot request the permission and the request result is *blocked*.**

*Screenshots*

[Step 1: The main screen of app with permission request button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8QO7.png)

[Step 2: The pop-out window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRLe3.png)

I click button at main screen(step 1), the step 2 will show and disappear quickly and back to screen at step 1.

I am new to React-Native, I don't know how to solve the problem. It is appreciated that anyone can help me to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

**Github Link**

https://github.com/TrifaC/HradwarePermissionTestApp.git

Answer (score 1):

Try `PermissionsAndroid` from `react-native` package

```
import { PermissionsAndroid} from "react-native";

const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
        message:
          "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
          "so you can take awesome pictures.",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera");
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Than you for your advice, I also try to implement this code block but the performance is same as I implement the "react-native-permission". The pop-up window show up and disappear quickly.

Comment: By the way, the function always return permission denied. However, I cannot find any permission about camera in the System Setting Page.

Comment: have you added permissions in ```AndroidManifest.xml``` file?

Comment: Sure. I added the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml. I Also try to use different brand Android Mobile Phone to test it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Please Add in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I want to know whether the Permission will appear in the system application setting page after we add the "uses-permission" ? Because I cannot see the them after add the code block